# FileReplacements vs Environment variables

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I have the case that I have to be able to deploy my Angular 6 project for two different servers, each with a slightly different API, user handling ect.
For this reason I added different abstraction layers in form of services to keep the interface to the rest of the code equal.

Because the files will have completely different content, I would like to write separate services in separate files and set only one set of services "active" for example to fetch data, handle the user ect.

```
app/
├── core/
│   ├── Server1.user.service.ts
│   ├── Server2.user.service.ts
│   ├── Server1.data.service.ts
│   ├── Server2.data.service.ts
│   └── ...
├── components/
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

What I want to avoid by that is having a lot of `if (deployedForServer1) {...}`  in my code, as this is hard to maintain and difficult to keep an overview.

Now I am unsure, what is the best way to implement this.

My first approach would be to do it by replacing the services with "fileReplacements" in the angular.json. This has the advantage that only the code I need will be deployed, but results in a rather complicated angular.json configuration.

Another way would be to handle it over environment variables, but here I am not sure if I can avoid having multiple `if (deployedForServer1) {...}`-like querys in my code.

I dont mean this question to be one to answer with opinions, but rather information if one of these approaches is fundamentaly wrong or has any severe downsides I don't see right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second implementation `if(deployedForServer1) { ... }` is wrong and will become absolute nightmare for maintenance. If something changes, for example new api address, or new port, you will need to change the code and deploy new production version. Additionally, it scales very bad. If you want to deploy the app in 5 other servers, you will need to add that in the code.

If only the host address is what is dynamic, then you want to follow the principle: build once, deploy everywhere.

You can create a service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    private appSettings: any = {};

    setAppConfig() {

        if(environment.production) {
            return this.http.get('config.json')
                .toPromise()
                .then(apiKeys => {
                    this.appSettings = apiKeys;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error)
                    return Promise.reject();
                })
        } else {
            this.appSettings = environment.configToApi;
            return Promise.resolve();
        }

    }

    getAppSettings() {
        return this.appSettings;
    }
}
```

Then you will call the `setAppConfig()` function in your `app.module` using `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```js
{
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
              return () => {
                  return appConfig.setAppConfig();
              }
          },
          multi: true,
          deps: [AppConfigService]
}
```

You see, the service reads a local file `config.json`, which will hold server specific configurations:

```
{
    "apiAddress": "...",
    "apiAddress2": "..."
}
```

The configuration is stored in the `appSettings` object in the service, and you can access the configuration anytime by calling `getAppSettings()`.

The advantages of this approach are:

1. You build only once, and you can deploy everywhere
2. The configuration is set during runtime, instead build time. This means that any server configuration can be changed without building/deploying a new version.

Comment: This is a very good approach, I will definitely need as well. Unfortunately difference its much more than some constants, its a whole different API that requires serious abstraction, so just a configuration file wont do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'd go with different configurations in `angular.json`, since you need to replace whole different APIs and abstractions etc.